# How to authorize system calls in spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I implemented spring security in my web application. Now all my services are secured and can be only invoked by authorized users. Everything works on webside, but if I invoke method via JMX or by quartz spring throw exception "Access denied". Now I created "fake" user and I log him at jmx method start, but I dont think its good solution. How I should do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to partition the application into an “internal” set of beans that just implement the methods, and an “external” set of beans that present the “internal” operations to the web. The security annotations can go on the “external” beans, and the JMX/Quartz-driven access be performed directly on the “internal” beans (or suitable other delegates).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what when I have shared methods, which I use in the "external" and "internal" operations ?

Comment: @Konrad Are these associated with conceptually basic utilities? If so, they're easy to factor out and _should be_ factored out. Otherwise, they're a sign that you've got design incoherence and need to spend a bit of time refactoring to get the coherence back. Sometimes that can take a redesign (and if it does, so be it; it's super-difficult to get the design right first time).